# How to apply pagination on two different models in rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

I want to apply pagination on two tables.

messages

```
Id    Message         Created at
1     Message One     2012-04-23 13:11:23
2     Message Two     2012-04-23 13:11:26
3     Message Three   2012-04-23 13:11:27
```

bids

```
Id    Comment         Created at
1     Comment One     2012-04-23 13:11:24
2     Comment Two     2012-04-23 13:11:25
3     Comment Three   2012-04-23 13:11:28
```

I want following result (Two latest bids or messages) using one query

```
   Id    Content         Created at
    3     Comment Three   2012-04-23 13:11:28
    3     Message Three   2012-04-23 13:11:27
```

Comment: Google: "Pagination in Rails"
You're flooded with options!

Comment: Also, numerous duplicates!
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pagination+rails

Comment: @Aayush Kumar:- There are some parameters like query optimization.... I am not fool asking such a simple question......you mean if i want to show 2 latest from 1000 messages and 1000 bids then i need to fetch 2000 records and then apply pagination???.......I dont want to pull all the bids, all the messages and then apply pagination on it......

Comment: Rather than asking such a broad and open question, perhaps, it would be better for all of us if you tell us what exactly you've tried, what you want - what worked and what didn't for you?

Comment: I think whatever i mentioned in question is enough to understand what i want......please read it carefully.....and if still you don't get it, i am sorry i don't explain any better than this.....also i expecting someone will answer my question and meanwhile if i get i answer i do post here..

Answer (score 0):

Taking a step back, may I ask why you need two separate tables for Messages and Bids. To me, both look like they store some form of text notification. I guess you should be using Single Table Inheritance or Polymorphic association (in case, there would be other business logic coming in the future).

Please check out [this blog](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html) to know more.

I think this very requirement that your pagination is spanning across two tables is a design smell. I don't have the full context and I am not sure if you have the liberty of changing the design now. But, just a thought!

Comment: Whatever given in the question is not my real database structure.....there are 5 more columns in each of the table......I know Polymorphisom.....but here in this case i cant use Polymorphisom

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, paginating record from **multiple tables** is a code smell.

Still if you want to go with this BAD approach, following code might be helpful for you:

```
records = [Message, Comment, Post].inject([]) do |record, with_class|
  record+with_class.order('created_at DESC')#you can add limit, offset here
end


#Now paginate those records

@records = WillPaginate::Collection.create(current_page, per_page, records.size) do         |pager|
            pager.replace(@records)
           end
```